# Getting union of files after the combination generated from command line in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, combinations, command-line-arguments

I want to write a python program where I want to take `n` number of command line arguments.

For an example : `python3 myProgram.py 3 A B C`

In the above example `n = 3` and the 3 arguments are `A, B, C`

Now 1st I want to generate all the combinations of those `n` arguments except for the empty one. For the above example it will be : `A, B, C, AB, AC, BC, ABC`

So I am going to get `2^n-1` number of combinations.

For the above part I am trying like:

```
import sys
import itertools 
from itertools import combinations

number = int(sys.argv[1]);

a_list=list(sys.argv[2:number+2])

all_combinations = []
for r in range(len(a_list) + 1):
    combinations_object = itertools.combinations(a_list, r)
    combinations_list = list(combinations_object)
    all_combinations += combinations_list

print(all_combinations)
```

But here I am unable to remove the empty combination.

Now initially I have `n` files in that same directory. For an example in above case, I have 3 files : `A.txt, B.txt, C.txt`

Now after that for each combination I want to generate an output file like:

When it is only A then the `outputfile_1 = A.txt`

When it is only B then the `outputfile_2 = B.txt`

When it is only C then the `outputfile_3 = C.txt`

When it is AB then the `outputfile_4 = union (A.txt, B.txt)`

...

so on

When it is ABC then the `outputfile_7 = union (A.txt, B.txt, C.txt)`

So for this above example if I run the code like : `python3 myProgram.py 3 A B C` then I am going to get 7 output files as output.

And if it is `python3 myProgram.py 4 A B C D` then I am going to get 15 output files as output.

To use the concept of `Union`, I am trying to use the logic:

```
with open("A.txt") as fin1: lines = set(fin1.readlines())
with open("B.txt") as fin2: lines.update(set(fin2.readlines()))
with open("outputfile_4.txt", 'w') as fout: fout.write('\n'.join(list(lines)))
```

But I am unable to understand how to merge these 2 things and get my desired outcome. Please help me out.

Comment: Regarding _"But here I am unable to remove the empty combination"_: You could do `r in range(1, len(a_list) + 1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably two separate questions. The first is how to get all of the combinations where `n` is greater than 0. @timus was on the right track there. To make their answer more complete:

1. Use list comprehension to generate a list of itertools.combinations objects
2. Use nested list comprehension to make a one-dimension list of tuples

```
matrix = [itertools.combinations(a_list, r) for r in range(1, len(a_list) + 1)]
combinations = [c for combinations in matrix for c in combinations]
```

The second question seems a bit less clear. I'm not sure if it's how to iterate the combinations, how to get filenames from the combinations, or something else. I've provided a sample implementation below (python3.6+).

```
import sys
import itertools 

def union(files):
    lines = set()
    for file in files:
        with open(file) as fin:
            lines.update(fin.readlines())
    return lines

def main():
    number = int(sys.argv[1]);
    a_list=sys.argv[2:number+2]
    
    matrix = [itertools.combinations(a_list, r) for r in range(1, len(a_list) + 1)]
    combinations = [c for combinations in matrix for c in combinations]
    for combination in combinations:
        filenames = [f'{name}.txt' for name in combination]
        output = f'{"".join(combination)}_output.txt'
        print(f'Writing union of {filenames} to {output}')
        with open(output, 'w') as fout:
            fout.writelines(union(filenames))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This will do my job pretty well. Just one more thing, as I want to show all the possible combinations as well when the program executes. So my output screen will look something like : `(A) , (B), (C), (A,B), (A,C), (B,C), (A,B,C)` and then `Writing union of ['A.txt'] to A_output.txt
Writing union of ['B.txt'] to B_output.txt` ... and so on. What should I add inside your code for this purpose?

Comment: I just need a little modification in this above code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70068069/counting-the-command-line-arguments-and-removing-the-not-needed-one-in-python can you please help? It will be a huge help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can put the following immediately before the `for` loop to show the list of combinations. `print(combinations)`. If you don't want it to be printed with the square brackets, you can do `print(' '.join([str(c) for c in combinations]))` instead.