# Counting the command line arguments and removing the not needed one in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, command-line-arguments

I want to write  python code which will be run using the following command :

```
python3 myProgram.py 4 A B C D stemfile
```

Where 4 is the number of files and A,B,C,D are 4 files.Then I wanted to generate all the combinations of A,B,C,D except the empty one.`(A, B, C, D, AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD, ABC, ABD, ACD, BCD, ABCD)` But before that it will read the `stemfile.names` and if `stemfile.names` has a line `| Final Pseudo Deletion Count is 0.` Then only it will generate the above 15 combination, else it will say `noisy data` and will not print the combinations of 3 files and not consider D. So the output will be : `(A, B, C, AB, AC, BC, ABC)`

So in my code what I did is, I always took D as the last file arguments and ran that loop 1 time less. But it is not always true that D will be the last argument only. It can be like : `python3 myProgram.py 4 B D C A stemfile`

In this case, in my code the A will not be considered while making the combinations, But whenever that line will not be found in the `stemfile.names`, I just want to remove D file from the equation. How should I do that?

And later in that code, when the combination is A only it will store the A in a seperate outputfile, whenever it is AB then it stores the union of A,B files in a separate  files and so on for all the combinations. Here also if there is noisy data then that D file will not come in any of the outputfile.

One more example, If I give : `python3 myProgram.py 3 A D B stemfile`

And the `stemfile.names` doesn't have the line `| Final Pseudo Deletion Count is 0.` then the output combinations are : `A,B,AB` and it will create 2 output files only.

Below I am attaching my code:

```
import sys
import itertools
from itertools import combinations


def union(files):
    lines = set()
    for file in files:
        with open(file) as fin:
            lines.update(fin.readlines())
    return lines


def main():
    number = int(sys.argv[1])
    dataset = sys.argv[number+2]

    with open(dataset+'.names') as myfile:
        if '| Final Pseudo Deletion Count is 0.' in myfile.read():
            a_list = sys.argv[2:number+2]
            print("All possible combinations:\n")
            for L in range(1, len(a_list)+1):
                 for subset in itertools.combinations(a_list, L):
                     print(*list(subset), sep=',')
            print("...............................")
            matrix = [itertools.combinations(a_list, r) 
                      for r in range(1, len(a_list) + 1)]
            combinations = [c for combinations in matrix for c in combinations]
            for combination in combinations:
                filenames = [f'{name}' for name in combination]
                output = f'{"".join(combination)}_output'
                print(f'Writing union of {filenames} to {output}')
                with open(output, 'w') as fout:
                    fout.writelines(union(filenames))

        else:
            a_list = sys.argv[2:number+1]
            # Here I am reducing a number only
            
            print("Noisy data.\n")
            print("So all possible combinations:\n")

            for L in range(1, len(a_list)+1):
                for subset in itertools.combinations(a_list, L):
                    print(*list(subset), sep=',')
            print("................................")
            matrix = [itertools.combinations(a_list, r)
                      for r in range(1, len(a_list) + 1)]
            combinations = [c for combinations in matrix for c in combinations]
            for combination in combinations:
                filenames = [f'{name}' for name in combination]
                output = f'{"".join(combination)}_output'
                print(f'Writing union of {filenames} to {output}')
                with open(output, 'w') as fout:
                    fout.writelines(union(filenames))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please help me out.

Comment: I think you're putting in quite a bit of effort to parse command line arguments when you could be using the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library. I don't have the time to write a full answer at the moment. For now, read up on the `argparse` library and see if you can figure it out on your own. I'll try to return later today and see if you still need help. Hint: `nargs='+'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should probably break this down into smaller, more specific questions. It seems like there is a lot of detail here that's not focused on the specific problem you're facing. I took a shot at what I think you're asking, however.

I *think* you're trying to figure out how to remove an item from the command line arguments. If that's the case, there's nothing you can do about what's passed to the program, but you can modify the list of inputs after you parse. I really think you should try reading about the `argparse` library, as I stated in my comment. I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but here's some code using `argparse` that expects full filenames for each input file. The last argument must be the stemfile.

Once the arguments are parsed, you have list of `pathlib.Path` objects. You can simply remove the `D` file from the list.

```py
import argparse
import itertools
import pathlib

NOISY_DATA_LINE = '| Final Pseudo Deletion Count is 0.'

def get_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('filenames', type=pathlib.Path, nargs='+')
    parser.add_argument('stemfile', type=pathlib.Path)
    return parser

def union(files):
    lines = set()
    for file in files:
        with open(file) as fin:
            lines.update(fin.readlines())
    return lines

def main():
    parser = get_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()

    stemfile_lines = args.stemfile.read_text().splitlines()
    if stemfile_lines[-1] == NOISY_DATA_LINE:
        filenames = [p for p in args.filenames if p.stem != 'D']
    else:
        filenames = args.filenames

    matrix = [itertools.combinations(filenames, r) for r in range(1, len(filenames) + 1)]
    combinations = [c for combinations in matrix for c in combinations]
    print(' '.join([str([p.stem for p in c]) for c in combinations]))
    for combination in combinations:
        output = f'{"".join([p.stem for p in combination])}_output.txt'
        print(f'Writing union of {[p.stem for p in combination]} to {output}')
        with open(output, 'w') as fout:
            fout.writelines(union(filenames))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for the help.